# Cypress Security Error. Can only call open() on same-origin documents

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, browser-automation

I'm learning Cypress and decided to test a 3d party website as a practice. This 3dparty website uses subdomains. (ex catalog.main.com, cart.main.com, news.main.com)

So I set a base Url (main.com) in cypress.json file. But for some reason I get the following error when running my tests `Security Error Failed to execute 'open' on 'Document': Can only call open() on same-origin documents.`

So I tried to remove the base URL and use a separate subdomain URL for each test. And got even more Security errors like above.

Could you please tell me how can I get rid of this error?

P.S. I set "chromeWebSecurity: false" in my cypress.json file

Comment: Why are you using open? Try cy.visit()

Comment: I use cy.visit(). But it throws this error though

Comment: what is more interestingly at first the page appears to be loading then when get cookie command is reached this error is thrown